# Implement Docusign in Symfony with Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, docusignapi

I'm trying to implement Docusign in a Symfony backend with Doctrine. I tried the quickstart and that works perfectly but now I struggle with implementing it.

I followed the [how-to guide](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/request-signature-in-app-embedded/) but it's not clear which piece goes in which file and how I can connect the Auth0, that is already in the project, to the new Docusign file(s). It seems like some parts are missing or it's not clear on how exactly to implement it. I tried implementing some parts of the quickstart but some files seem unnecessary in my case.

I would love to be able to sign by one custom API call from the frontend to the backend, with all the needed input fields, to make the connection to Docusign.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it takes more than one custom API call.

First, figure out what you want to happen. Who supplies the document(s) to be signed? Who sends the transaction out? How do you know the signers are who they say they are (authentication)? Who gets a copy of the signed documents? Are the signed documents stored/archived somewhere in addition to being stored on the DocuSign system? Etc. Then:

Step 1. Obtain a DocuSign access token via OAuth. There are multiple OAuth flows available, depending on your use case.

Step 2. Create and send the DocuSign transaction ("envelope"). Envelopes have a huge number of options.

Often it is best to create an envelope `template` by using the DocuSign application. Then, your software just fills in the template's details and sends it.

Ask additional *specific* questions on StackOverflow as they arise.

Comment: Thanks for the info! 

Here is some more context:
- it's is a web application that creates contracts for new employees after they filled in their information
- the documents are created in a directory in the backend and they get filled in by the inputs of the forms before the new employee press the sign button
- both the admin and new employee get the signed documents by email
- they get stored in backend of the app
- the admin and employee created an account on Auth0 before signing

I created what I need to do in the quickstart but it's of course not implemented into my application.

Comment: Ok, very doable. What, specifically, is your question? (And ask it as a new question.) Questions should be specific and include what you've tried that didn't work.